# visual studio 2019 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Everytime I run debugger I receive this message in the output:

```
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\123em\OneDrive\Project1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
The thread 0x23e1c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[139372] Project1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

How can I see the result of my project? I am building a code to rotate an array.

Comment: Does your program generate any output?  Might help if we could see it...

Comment: What happens if you have a debugger breakpoint on the first line of `main`?

Comment: Go to the first line of `int main()` and press `F9` to add a breakpoint. Then run again and see if it stops on your breakpoint. After that `F10` and `F11` will help you to advance to the next statement.

Comment: :\Users\123em\OneDrive\Project1.exe (process 1696) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . . this is the message i receive in the debug console. I tried using the breakpoints as mentioned in the previous comments & have the same results

Comment: So it did or didn't stop on the first line of `main()`?

Comment: Both outputs you have showed indicate that the program ran fine and ended without error. You would expect the same output for a "Hello World" application.

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of result you expect, so I listed two methods for your reference.

1. Set a breakpoint and add the variable you want to monitor in "Add item to watch", so that you can observe the value of the variable, and it needs to be used with F11, I suggest you refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022) for this.

[image]

2. Right-click the breakpoint, then select Action, and enter your ideal output format. When executing the program, you can see the output you set in output.
   [image]